# Gaussian Log Likelyhood loss function in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gaussian, autoencoder, loss

I need to implement a gaussian log likelihood loss function in Tensorflow, however I am not sure if what I wrote is correct. I think [this](http://theanets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/theanets.losses.GaussianLogLikelihood.html#theanets.losses.GaussianLogLikelihood) is the correct definition of the loss function.

I went around implementing it like this:

```
    two_pi = 2*np.pi

    def gaussian_density_function(x, mean, stddev):

        stddev2 = tf.pow(stddev, 2)
        z = tf.multiply(two_pi, stddev2)
        z = tf.pow(z, 0.5)

        arg = -0.5*(x-mean)
        arg = tf.pow(arg, 2)
        arg = tf.div(arg, stddev2)

        return tf.divide(tf.exp(arg), z)


    mean_x, var_x = tf.nn.moments(dae_output_tensor, [0])
    stddev_x = tf.sqrt(var_x)

    loss_op_AE = -gaussian_density_function(inputs, mean_x, stddev_x)
    loss_op_AE = tf.reduce_mean(loss_op_AE)
```

I want to use this as the loss function for an autoencoder, however, I am not sure this implementation is correct, since I get a NaN out of loss_op_AE.

EDIT: I also tried using:

```
    mean_x, var_x = tf.nn.moments(autoencoder_output, axes=[1,2])
    stddev_x = tf.sqrt(var_x)

    dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(mean_x, stddev_x)
    loss_op_AE = -dist.pdf(inputs)
```

and I get the same NaN values.

Answer (score 2):

Model the stddev as log stddev, this should fix the nan issue. So instead of pretending stddev is sigma^2, pretend it is the natural logarithm of sigma^2.